# Solution method for $y'=f(\frac{a_1 x + b_1 y + c_1}{a_2 x + b_2 y + c_2 })$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

What kind of a solution method will work for this equation? My book hints, that this may be solved with the method used for $y'=\frac{a_1 x + b_1 y + c_1}{a_2 x + b_2 y + c_2 }$. That is, first I substitute $x=\xi+h$ and $y=\eta +k$. This lead to $$y'=f\Biggr(\frac{a_1 \xi + b_1 \eta + (a_1h+b_1k+c_1)}{a_2 \xi + b_2 \eta +(a_2h+b_2k+ c_2) }\Biggr)$$

Then we can solve the linear system for the variables $h,k$ so that we are left with $$y'=f\Biggr(\frac{a_1 \xi + b_1 \eta}{a_2 \xi + b_2 \eta }\Biggr)$$

then making the substitution $\eta = u\xi$ leads to $$\eta'=f\Biggr(\frac{a_1 \xi + b_1 u\xi}{a_2 \xi + b_2 u\xi }\Biggr)$$

and $$u'\xi+u= f\Biggr(\frac{a_1 +u}{a_2 +u }\Biggr)$$

which can then be transformed into an equation with variables separated, by reducing $u$ and taking the reciprocal of the right side. This is the equation $$\frac{1}{\xi}d\xi= \biggr(f\Biggr(\frac{a_1 +u}{a_2 +u }\Biggr)-u\Biggr)^{-1}du$$

Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed $b_1, b_2$ but otherwise looks alright.

$$\frac{1}{\xi}d\xi= \biggr(f\Biggr(\frac{a_1 +b_1u}{a_2 +b_2u }\Biggr)-u\Biggr)^{-1}du$$
And so,
$$\log(x-h) = \int \biggr(f\Biggr(\frac{a_1 +b_1u}{a_2 +b_2u }\Biggr)-u\Biggr)^{-1}du, u = \frac{y-k} {x-h}$$